# 'Truth value of an array is ambiguous' error with np.fromfunction

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to use the numpy.fromfunction to compute an array defined by a function but I got an error that I do not understand.

d_matrix is a distance matrix and the error message I get is "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()". I put dtype = int in the np.fromfunction because I read that could the solution.

```
def v(r, i):
    return 1/N*np.sum(d_matrix[i,:]<r)

def rho_barre(r):
    return quad(rho, r, np.inf)[0]

def grad_F(i, j):
    return quad( lambda r : ( (v(r, i) + v(r, j))/2 - v_r) * rho_barre(max(r, d_matrix[i,j])),  0,  np.inf)[0]

Grad_F = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: grad_F(i,j), (N,N), dtype=int)
```

I'd like to know if someone may help me with this error and more generally if someone has an idea of what to do in order to compute an array defined by a function. I'm not sure I'm doing the fastest thing

Comment: `fromfunction` passes the whole `np.indices(N,N)`  to your function, at once.  It doesn't do it iteratively.  Look at the code for `fromfunction`.  I'd suggest using a double loop over the `range(N)`s instead.  Posters often misunderstand the use of `fromfunction`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, [`np.fromfunction`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) provides arrays of indices, not individual index tuples. This is a common mistake, but working with index arrays is usually more efficient. If you really must produce a single value at a time, you could use a function like this instead:

```
import numpy as np

def fromfunction_iter(function, shape, dtype=None):
    # Iterator over all index tuples
    iter = np.ndindex(*shape)
    # First index
    idx = next(iter)
    # Produce first value
    value = function(*idx)
    # Make it into a NumPy value
    value = np.asarray(value, dtype=dtype)
    # Make output array of the right data type
    out = np.empty(shape, dtype=value.dtype)
    # Set first value
    out[idx] = value
    # Fill rest of values
    for idx in iter:
        out[idx] = function(*idx)
    return out
```

However, this will generally be much slower, and in fact if you have to run some iterative algorithm like this with NumPy data you may need to look into something like Numba if you want to make it run really fast.